# Can canvas in flexbox with flex=1 be done without extra container?

Tags: html, css, canvas, flexbox

I want to display canvas with flex=1 in flexbox and I want canvas to have same width/height attributes as it's physical size so I use:

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

The moment I do that the canvas will not shrink when I make page smaller. I've tried this:

```
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

But it doesn't work, nor any other things I've tried. I have wrap canvas in extra container:

```js
var f = footer.clientWidth;

function line() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

narrower.onclick = function () {
  footer.style.width = (footer.clientWidth - 20) + 'px';
  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  line();
}

wider.onclick = function () {
  footer.style.width = (footer.clientWidth + 20) + 'px';
  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  line();
}
```

```css
footer {
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  outline: 2px solid fuchsia;
}

#container {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid lime;
}

canvas {
  outline: 1px dashed cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <button id="narrower">narrower</button>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas">aaa</canvas>
  </div>
  <button id="wider">wider</button>
</footer>
```

My question is, can it be done without extra container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, is it what you try to do :

```js
var f = footer.clientWidth;

function line() {
  var ctx = container.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(container.width, container.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}

narrower.onclick = function() {
footer.style.width = (footer.clientWidth - 20) + 'px';
  container.width = container.clientWidth;
  container.height = container.clientHeight;
  line();
}

wider.onclick = function() {
  footer.style.width = (footer.clientWidth + 20) + 'px';
  container.width = container.clientWidth;
  container.height = container.clientHeight;
  line();
}
```

```css
footer {
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  outline: 2px solid fuchsia;
}

#container {
  min-width: 0;
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid lime;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <button id="narrower">narrower</button>
  <canvas id="container">aaa</canvas>
  <button id="wider">wider</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: narrower is broken, can't test it. When I fix narrower at some point it stops shrinking and you can see that pixel ratio is not 1:1 with screen.

Comment: @asdjfiasd snippet updated after being advised from  termaniafif about the narrower function i did not pay attention to.